# How to DRY 'value.present? ? value == CONSTANT : self[:value] == CONSTANT'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to improve the following code, if possible. That is, is there a way to DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) the `CONSTANT` code in the following case?

```
def method(value = nil)
  value.present? ? value == CONSTANT : self[:value] == CONSTANT
end
```

If so, how can I remove the "duplicated" `CONSTANT`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(value.present? ? value : self[:value]) == CONSTANT
```

Even better:

```
(value.presence || self[:value]) == CONSTANT
```

That then DRYs up the `value`. :-)

Comment: D'aw. You beat me to it.

Comment: The timestamps never lie.

Comment: @Matti Virkkunen - It depends... However, are brackets necessary or it is just for better "visualization"?

Comment: @Backo They are necessary. The conditional operator binds more loosely than `==`.

Comment: The parenthesis are needed to isolate the ternary statement.